# ActionMailer::Base.deliveries returns array with duplicated values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, delayed-job

ActionMailer::Base.deliveries returns array with duplicated values. I am using rails 3.0.9 ruby 1.9.2 and delayed_job3.0.pre. On test env it returns not duplicated values but in production they are duplicated.Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` is for testing purposes. You shouldn't use it on production.